# Empty reply from server

Tags: php, tor, php-curl

Oh, I've had enough of these incomprehensible errors that can't be fixed so easily. Requests are sent via php-tor to the onion site (I replaced the site address with site.onion). This time an error:

> Empty reply from server

The error does **not always** appear, it is somehow unclear, there is no pattern. But it appears quite often.
Which way to look at all? How to solve such problems or how to find the source of these problems? The request is sent exactly as from the browser, and the http headers are exactly the same. But for some reason the error message `Empty reply from server` is still sometimes haunts me.

The time on my server is set correctly. There are no problems with the Internet either.

```
$url = 'http://site.onion/images/uploads/xWzerY4349rr3m.jpg'; 

$headers = array('
 Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
 Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
 Connection: keep-alive
 Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0
');

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '127.0.0.1:9050');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5_HOSTNAME);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

$curl_info = curl_getinfo($ch);

$curl_error = curl_error($ch);

curl_close($ch);

if($curl_error) {
 echo $curl_error;
 print_r($curl_info);
} else {
 echo $response;
}
```

curl_getinfo($ch):

```
Array
(
    [url] => http://site.onion/images/uploads/xWzerY4349rr3m.jpg
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 0
    [header_size] => 0
    [request_size] => 1111
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 9.219219
    [namelookup_time] => 1.9E-5
    [connect_time] => 2.938378
    [pretransfer_time] => 2.938441
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 9.219207
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => 127.0.0.1
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 9050
    [local_ip] => 127.0.0.1
    [local_port] => 39532
    [request_header] => GET /images/uploads/xWzerY4349rr3m.jpg HTTP/1.1
Host: site.onion
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0
)
```

Comment: The site might be filtering out bot requests. Maybe you need to collect cookies and send them as well for every new request you make.

Comment: That being said, it's better to use a proper API.

Comment: @nice_dev, I've tried cookies too, and it's the same with them. The site is simple, it is unlikely that they can filter bots, and how? The IP is always visible as 127.0.0.1. They don't have an API :(

Comment: This is going through a proxy on your own server? Is there some way to narrow down whether the problem is between you and the proxy or the proxy and the remote site?

Comment: @ModaL Ok. I won't reproduce on my machine as I am bit reluctant to try for onion sites.

Comment: @GregSchmidt, I installed tor on my server (`apt-get install tor`) and use it to send a request to the onion site. Otherwise, you will not be able to access the onion site.  `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '127.0.0.1:9050');`

Comment: That's fine, my point is that there are two requests happening, one to your local proxy, and one from there to the final destination, and it's not clear from what you've shown here which one of those is failing. Figuring that out would seem to be an important step for you.

Comment: @GregSchmidt, If this is normal, what should users do? Repeat the request for this error?

Comment: I'm not saying the error is normal. I'm saying that the way you have set it up is a perfectly acceptable way to do it, but it means that there are two requests that happen, and to find and fix the error it would be helpful for you to know for sure which one is failing.

Comment: @GregSchmidt, And how do I understand which request needs to be corrected? Very often, right from the first request, this error occurs...

Comment: @GregSchmidt, Sometimes the server returns http_code = 303 and Empty reply from server, and sometimes the server returns http_code = 0 and Empty reply from server. Probably need to repeat those requests that have http_code = 0?

Comment: I've never used a proxy or tor or onion, so I don't have a solution for you. Just trying to help you to find the solution...